# Add favorite button ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, i want to add a favorite button in my view show internship, but i get this error : {:favorite_internship=>["must exist"]}

I don't known how to tell rails that the id of the show view internship is the favorite_internship_id

I've tried this in internship controller but it doesn't work

@favorite.favorite_internship_id = @internship.id

First, the table Favorite, Internship has the class_name 'favorite_internship' and User has the class_name 'favorite_user'

```
  create_table "favorites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "favorite_user_id"
    t.bigint "favorite_internship_id"
    t.index ["favorite_internship_id"], name: "index_favorites_on_favorite_internship_id"
    t.index ["favorite_user_id"], name: "index_favorites_on_favorite_user_id"
  end
```

Favorite model

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :favorite_user, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :favorite_internship, class_name: "Internship"
end
```

Internship model

```
class Internship < ApplicationRecord

 has_many :favorites, foreign_key: "favorite_internship_id"
 has_many :favorite_users, foreign_key: "favorite_user_id", class_name: "User", through: :favorites

end
```

Favorite Controller

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
def new
    @favorite = Favorite.new
end

def create
    @favorite = Favorite.new(favorite_internship_id: params[:favorite_internship_id], favorite_user_id: params[:favorite_user_id])
    @favorite.favorite_user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @favorite.save
        format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, notice: 'Favorite was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @favorite }
      else
        format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, notice: "Le favoris n'a pas pu être créé : #{@favorite.errors.messages}" }
        format.json { render json: @favorite.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end

end
```

So the favorite button is in the show internship. Here's the internship controller :

```
class InternshipsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @reviews_of_internship = @internship.reviews.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)
    @review = Review.new
    @favorite = Favorite.new
    @favorite.favorite_internship_id = @internship.id
  end
end
```

Routes

```
  resources :favorites

  resources :internships do 
    resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    resources :favorites, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  end
```

The create favorite route is :

```
 internship_favorites POST   /internships/:internship_id/favorites(.:format)                                          favorites#create
```

I have a button 'Favorite' in the view to click, so that the internship is favored

```
<%= button_to "Favorite", internship_favorites_path(@internship), method: :post %>
```

This is where i get the error '{:favorite_internship=>["must exist"]}'.

So if you have an advice on this, on how i should do it. Is the button a good idea or should i do it otherwise ?

Comment: Can you provide value of `params` and Favorite's associations ?

Comment: hum so i added the associations, for the params in Favorite, it's `(favorite_internship_id: params[:favorite_internship_id], favorite_user_id: params[:favorite_user_id])`

Answer (score 0):

you have favorite_internship model?
if yes than you have to add in you model that belongs to favorite

```
belongs_to :favorite, optional: true
```

Comment: Actually, non, that's not how i did it. I have a controller Favorite, which has a many to many association with the User and the Internship.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ! I didn't put this code :

```
@favorite.favorite_internship_id = @internship.id
```

In the right controller it should be in controller Favorite, in def #create, sorry i'm a beginner, anyway it woooooorks !!!

Also, i had a better advice which was to to that with the favorite params (in favorite controller #create):

```
@favorite = Favorite.new(favorite_internship_id: params[:internship_id], favorite_user_id: current_user.id)
```

I removed the other line, it works fine !